# i want to read the content of html and i need to change it with the required text

Tags: java, html, mysql, jsp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title id="title1">Amazon Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="p1">Hello World</p>
  <form action="Translate" method="post">
    <label id="l1">UserName</label><input type="text" name="uid"></br></br>
    <label id="l2">Password</label><input type="password" name="pwd"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="sub">
  </form>
  <p id="p2">Some text here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

how to get the content( say Amazon Home,Hello World,UserName,Password,submit,some text here) of above html to servlet or to jsp.... and in my database im having the equivalent text of content in another language as shown below . so if i get those strings from html to any layer then i have to replace the content with another strings(which are in my database).
(with out using javascript like `document.getElementById("l1").innerHTML="Nom d'utilisateur";)`

`-----+-------------+-------------------+
| id | f_key       | f_value           |
+----+-------------+-------------------+
|  1 | Hello_World | Bonjour le monde  |
|  2 | UserName    | Nom d'utilisateur |
|  3 | Password    | mot de passe      |
|  4 | submit      | soumettre         |
|  5 | Amazon_Home | Amazon Accueil    |
+----+-------------+-------------------+`

Comment: `<form action="<url_to_servlet>" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

use Resource bundle in jsp to change the text depending on your case

Comment: for ResourceBundle need to use .properties file but im not using .properties file